# How to sign public PGP key with Bouncy Castle in Java

Tags: java, bouncycastle, gnupg, pgp

I'm writing PGP server to generate keys for users.
I want to sign any generated PGP public key with my private key in Java with Bouncy Castle, to make it trusted for my users.

I have no problems with generating key pair - it works perfect.

I tried to sign by gpg --sign-key command line and it works good.

But I can't get the same in Java. I tried many solutions like this: [java sign public pgp key with bouncycastle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591684/java-sign-public-pgp-key-with-bouncycastle)

and DirectKeySignature class from BC examples package, but nothing works for my.

Key is signed but gpg --check-sigs tell that signature is incorrect:

```
gpg --check-sigs "Adrian (test) <al@p-c.pl>"
pub   4096R/9D5D4AB8 2018-06-20
sig-         E9798A8A 2018-08-04  Test (test) <test@sample.com>
uid                  Adrian (test) <al@p-c.pl>
sig!         9D5D4AB8 2018-06-20  Adrian (test) <al@p-c.pl>

1 incorrect signature
```

Source code in two versions:

version 1:

```
public void signKey(String id, PGPSecretKey mySecretKey, PGPPublicKey publicKeyToBeSigned, char[] passPhrase, OutputStream out) throws PGPException, IOException {

    PGPPrivateKey pgpPrivKey = mySecretKey.extractPrivateKey(
            new JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder().setProvider(provider).build(passPhrase));

    PGPSignatureGenerator signatureGenerator = new PGPSignatureGenerator(
            new JcaPGPContentSignerBuilder(mySecretKey.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm(), PGPUtil.SHA1));

    signatureGenerator.init(PGPSignature.DIRECT_KEY, pgpPrivKey);

    PGPSignature signature = signatureGenerator.generateCertification(id, publicKeyToBeSigned);

    PGPPublicKey result = PGPPublicKey.addCertification(publicKeyToBeSigned, signature);

    out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);

    result.encode(out);
    out.close();
}
```

version 2 (baset on org.bouncycastle.openpgp.examples.DirectKeySignature):

```
public void signPublicKey(PGPSecretKey secretKey, String secretKeyPass, PGPPublicKey keyToBeSigned, String notationName, String notationValue, OutputStream out) throws Exception {

    PGPPrivateKey pgpPrivKey = secretKey.extractPrivateKey(
            new JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(secretKeyPass.toCharArray()));

    PGPSignatureGenerator sGen = new PGPSignatureGenerator(
            new JcaPGPContentSignerBuilder(secretKey.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm(), PGPUtil.SHA1).setProvider("BC"));

    sGen.init(PGPSignature.DIRECT_KEY, pgpPrivKey);

    PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator spGen = new PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator();

    boolean isHumanReadable = true;

    spGen.setNotationData(true, isHumanReadable, notationName, notationValue);

    PGPSignatureSubpacketVector packetVector = spGen.generate();

    sGen.setHashedSubpackets(packetVector);

    PGPPublicKey result = PGPPublicKey.addCertification(keyToBeSigned, sGen.generate());

    out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);

    result.encode(out);
    out.close();
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void signKey() throws Exception {

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/secret.dat");

    PgpServiceImpl pgp = new PgpServiceImpl();

    PGPSecretKey pgpSecretKey = pgp.readSecretKey(in, "..........".toCharArray());
    PGPPublicKey pubKey = pgp.readPublicKey(new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/pub_other.dat"));

    ByteArrayOutputStream res = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    pgp.signPublicKey(pgpSecretKey, "..........", pubKey, "Test (test) <test@sample.com>", "Adrian (test) <al@p-c.pl>", res);

    System.out.println(new String(res.toByteArray()));
}
```

result:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG v1.60
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=9lxJ
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full source code you have so we can test it, as described on https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1):

this works perfectly:

```
public void signPublicKey(PGPSecretKey secretKey, char[] passPhrase, PGPPublicKey keyToBeSigned, OutputStream out) throws PGPException, IOException {

        PGPPrivateKey pgpPrivKey = secretKey.extractPrivateKey(
                new JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder().setProvider( provider )
                        .build(passPhrase));

        PGPSignatureGenerator signatureGenerator = new PGPSignatureGenerator(
                new JcaPGPContentSignerBuilder( secretKey.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm(), PGPUtil.SHA1 ) );

        signatureGenerator.init( PGPSignature.DEFAULT_CERTIFICATION, pgpPrivKey );

        Iterator<String> ids = keyToBeSigned.getUserIDs();
        if(!ids.hasNext()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("klucz nie posiada żadnego User ID");
        String id = ids.next();

        PGPSignature signature = signatureGenerator.generateCertification(id, keyToBeSigned);
        PGPPublicKey newKey = PGPPublicKey.addCertification(keyToBeSigned, id, signature);

        out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);

        newKey.encode(out);
        out.close();
    }
```